# Ubuntu Server samba running as root?

Tags: security, server, configuration, samba

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 10.04. I selected *samba file server* from the install menu and everything works fine. The problem is, the samba daemon is running as root which has me a little nervous.

I added a 'samba' group and a user called 'samba' to that group, but I can't get the daemon run under it.  MySQL from the LAMP seems to run as its own user.

Comment: This is not abandoned (it has a good, upvoted answer, and only unanswered questions can be considered abandoned), and it does appear to meet the description of *too localized* in any other way. I recommend we reopen this.

Answer (score 13):

Running Samba is slightly different to running apache or mysql.

When you connect to the web server all processes are run as user www-data, when you connect to mysqld all processes are run as user mysql.

But when you connect to samba a new process is forked with your user credentials.
Only root can fork processes as other users.

It is correct that samba is running as root.